# "...must have taken ‘after’ his daddy."

Tags: meaning, idioms, prepositions

I read this phrase:

> My son cracks me up. He's had me laughing all day long. Must have taken ***after*** his daddy.

I want to know what *after* means in this construction, and if there is some formal construction equivalent to this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To "take after" your father or mother means you inherited a trait from them, either genetically or by the way they raised you.

As an extension, you can "take after" anyone who might have an influence on you.  A student might take after his instructor.  You can take after your great-grandfather.  Et cetera.

Comment: Just a small tweak, this construct need not necessarily be applied to a father or mother.  It's pretty frequently applied to other relatives, and even non-relatives on occasion (though, obviously not in the genetic sense).

Comment: @Dusty - Good point.  Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

*To take after* means "have a similar appearance to or qualities in common with a parent or an ancestor."

Answer (score 2):

"After" in this usage is incomplete and meaningless by itself. The verb phrase is "to take after" and it means "to resemble" in myriad ways: sense of humor, taxicab ears (like the ones I have), ability to scheme successfully, musicality, and as many others as there are human traits real or imagined.

Comment: Probably related notionally to the idea of "taking after" someone also meaning to chase or follow them.

Comment: Sure, "take after" = "to follow"; nice thought. Whereas to "take OUT after" = "to follow carrying a shotgun"